# Stored procedure with CASE and WHERE coming from a table value parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

In a SQL Server stored procedure, can I use two separate columns from a table-valued parameter (TVP) in both the `CASE` and `WHERE` clauses?

In my TVP, I have two columns like so:

```
CREATE TYPE tt_Index AS TABLE
                        (
                            referenceType varchar(20),
                            referenceID varchar(20)
                        )
```

In the stored procedure, how can I iterate over the table parameter and use `referenceType` within a `CASE`, and `referenceID` within a `WHERE` clause?

Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp.Test
    @parIndexTable  tt_Index READONLY
AS
    SELECT 
        CASE (@parIndexTable.referenceType)
            WHEN 'ref1' THEN (SELECT * FROM NamesCurrent nc 
                              WHERE @parIndexTable.referenceID = nc.referenceID)
            WHEN 'ref2' THEN (UPDATE NamesCurrent nc 
                              SET nc.Name = 'Craig' 
                              WHERE @parIndexTable.referenceID = nc.referenceID)
        END
```

From what I've understood, I need to iterate over the TVP as a table but just unsure of the syntax for that and how it fits in with the case statement so I can use both parameters.

Comment: You **CANNOT** put entire code blocks inside the `THEN` part of a `CASE`. `CASE` is an **expression** that returns a single atomic value - you cannot use it to conditionally execute one code block or another

Comment: What you want is impossible even with normal tables. `CASE` is an expression, not a statement, and can't contain statements like `SELECT` or `UPDATE`. A table must appear in  a FROM clause.

Comment: Besides, SQL, the language, is set based. You don't iterate over rows, you write a query that does something, eg INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE with the results of the query. You can use `MERGE` to insert or update rows into a target table, although that's no more efficient than two separate statements, one UPDATE to update existing rows and an INSERT to insert new ones

Comment: Thanks for this info. In my limited wisdom, I guess I only wanted to ‘iterate’ through the tvp once, and perform an action based on each row of the tvp depending on what the reference was. 

Sounds like I’ll have to do run my query many times against the same tvp and just join my records to get what I need.

Comment: @Craig When using SQL try to avoid thinking about "iteration" (because SQL doesn't have loops), instead recall back to your high-school level math classes about set-theory because SQL is all about working with sets (specifically, [sets of tuples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra)). And I'm highly doubtful that you will need to run your query many times... the way to use TVPs in queries is usually to JOIN them once (e.g. for an exclusion filter, use an _anti-join_), also consider `CROSS APPLY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must admit, the logic you have seems odd here, as you have a `SELECT` and an `UPDATE` and you want to `SELECT` from that `UPDATE`(?). As you want both a `SELECT` and an `UPDATE` on different thing, you need to statements here; one for the `SELECT` which doesn't `UPDATE` anything and another for the `UPDATE`, which *assume* also needs an `OUTPUT` clause.

To use the TVP, you just need to use a `JOIN` and you can filter the rows in the `SELECT`/`UPDATE` in the `WHERE`.

This results in the following statements:

```sql
SELECT NC.{Explicit List of Columns}
FROM dbo.NamesCurrent NC
     JOIN @parIndexTable pIT ON NC.referenceID = pIT.referenceID 
WHERE pIT.referenceType = 'ref1';

UPDATE NC
SET Name = 'Craig'
OUTPUT NC.{Explicit List of Columns} --I assume you want this too?
FROM dbo.NamesCurrent NC
     JOIN @parIndexTable pIT ON NC.referenceID = pIT.referenceID 
WHERE pIT.referenceType = 'ref2';
```

Comment: Thank you Larnu. It’s clear to me now that return submits the comment and doesn’t not instil a carriage return. Following on from my single comment of thanks I did add further gratitude and seek further clarity but I’ve given up . I will delete this question now. Sorry to have taken up your time. Regards

Comment: You can't delete a question that has an upvoted answer, @Craig , and I would (personally) urge against deleting the question; of your undeleted questions only one has upvotes, and the rest all a score of 0 or less. Deleted questions with a score of <= 0 are weighted much more heavily by the algorithm towards rate limiting a user from asking further questions. I can't see how many deleted questions you have, but you could find that deleting this question could be enough to "break the ice" and land you into a question ban.

Comment: What question remains, @Craig ? *If* my answer doesn't answer the question, as your prior (now deleted) comment implied it did, then explain why it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, not having a good day. Meant I won’t delete the question.